# expression meaning: formula.split ("[\\ *]") and obj1.replaceAll ("\\.", "");

Tags: java, regex

please, the meaning of these lines of code?

```
// What is meant by formula.split ("[\\ *]"); ???

 String[] temp = formula.split("[\\*]");

//Indicate what they want and why these substitutions twice on the same subject ??? Does this have a specific meaning ???

obj1 = obj1.replaceAll ("\\.", "");
obj1 = obj1.replaceAll (",", ".");
```

Thanks to those who will give me explanations

Comment: One splits on `'*'`. The replaceAll removes periods, and replaces a commas with a period. This seems to convert (imperfectly) a number representation with thousand groups using a period, and decimals using a comma, into a number representation for the programming language, like `Double.parseDouble(obj1)`. Maybe in some European country (NL, DE, BE).

Answer (score 0):

**`split()`, `replaceAll()` and Regular Expressions**

The [`split()`](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_string_split.htm) function actually accepts [regular expression patterns](http://www.rexegg.com/) to handle splitting operations as opposed to using normal strings that you might expect.

```
// This would take your string and split it on an explicit '*' character
String[] temp = formula.split("[\\*]");
```

The pattern `[\\*]` is a character set that will match an explicit asterisk `*` as the `\\` are generally used as escape characters. So when once is encountered, it will be added to your output array :

```
// Example use-case
String[] temp = "a\b*c".split("[\\*]"); // yields ["a\b","c"]
```

Likewise, the [`replaceAll()`](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_string_replaceall.htm) function also accepts a regular expression to handle replacements.

```
// This would replace any periods with commas (escaping is required as '.' matches all) 
obj1 = obj1.replaceAll ("\\.", "");
// This would replace and commas with periods (no escaping required as ',' isn't special)
obj1 = obj1.replaceAll (",", ".");
```

Since these two operations are doing two separate things, you really can't combine them (the first is replacing characters that follow slashes and the other replaces commas with periods).

Comment: this isn't correct since the first `\ ` will be used by Java to escape the following `\ ` and this one will be used by regex to escape the `*` or `.`

Answer (score 0):

first will split on ever * found in a string.
`"foo*bar*war*boo".split("[\\*]"); => [foo, bar, war, boo]`

second will remove all `.`'s

third will change all `,` to `.`

Answer (score 0):

```
String[] temp = formula.split("[\\*]");
```

It splits a string into parts when it meets `*` sign. `"[\\*]"` is a regex which tells us where to split the string. `\\` was used, because `*` is a special character in regex.

```
obj1 = obj1.replaceAll ("\\.", "");
```

This line removes all the `.` in `obj1`.

```
obj1 = obj1.replaceAll (",", ".");
```

This line replaces every `,` in `obj1` with `.`.

Here are some examples:

```
String s = "it*is*string";
String[] tmp = s.split("[\\*]");
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(tmp));
String s1 = "remove .dots.,please,.";
s1 = s1.replaceAll("\\.", "");
s1 = s1.replaceAll (",", ".");
System.out.println(s1);
```

Output:

```
[it, is, string]
remove dots.please.
```